# jQuery check if two values is blank

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three values:

```
var tbb = $("#total1 span").text();
var tmb = $("#total2 span").text();
var tab = $("#total3 span").text();
```

Each of them could be blank.

What is the better way in javascript/jquery check if two of these values is blank?

UPDATE

here is what i mean, my a bit ugly and a "lot of lines" solution

```
var i = 0;
            if (tab != "") {
                i++;
            }

            if (tmb != "") {
                i++;
            }

            if (tbb != "") {
                i++;
            }

            if (i >= 2) {
                //do something
            }
```

Any better thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(tbb == null || tbb == ''){...}
```

And the same for the rest.

Comment: pretty sure `text()` will always return a string. thus checking for null is not needed.

Comment: @mikeycgto -- that may be true.

Answer (score 1):

```
var twoAreEmpty = $("#total1, #total2, #total3").find("span:empty").length === 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var twoblank = 
  $("#tota11 span, #total2 span, #total3 span")
    .filter(function(index){
      return !$(this).text().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    })
    .length === 2;
```

Also, you probably mean `#total1`, not `#tota11` - just sayin.

Answer (score 0):

if (tab == "") should be enough shouldn't it?

Does .text() ever return blank?

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = [tmb, tbb, tab].filter(function( str ) {
    return !str.length;
});

if( filtered.length === 2 ) {
    console.log('yay, two empty values: ', filtered); 
}
```

Comment: .filter isn't a standard JS function, you probably mean to wrap your native array with jQuery.

Comment: @jimbojw: you're wrong sir. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: sorry, I'll rephrase - .filter isn't supported by all browsers you probably care about, irrespective of whether it has recently been added to a standard

Comment: @jimbojw: I guess any browser that supports Javascript 1.6

Comment: Agreed: so modern browsers and IE 9+.  Until I can run something in IE, I tend to ignore it.  For example, I can't wait for the day when I can [a,b]=[1,2], but alas, that day may never come.

Comment: I'm probably not so shy about using this since I'm using an abstraction layer in all my codes to support 5years old+ browsers.

Comment: @jAndy let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1588/discussion-between-jimbojw-and-jandy)

Answer (score 0):

Just try it.

```
var i = 0; 
if(tbb.length == 0 )
{  
    i++
}
 if(tmb.length == 0 )
{  
    i++
} 
if(tab.length == 0 )
{  
    i++
}  
if(i >=2)  
{
   //perform operation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but this is going to be a single-line solution for what you want.

```
if (((tab == '' ? 1 : 0) + (tmb == '' ? 1 : 0) + (tbb == '' ? 1 : 0)) > 1){
    // Do Something
}
```

Answer (score -1):

All valid answers, but forgetting about undefined :)

```
if(tbb === '' || tbb === null || tbb === undefined){ // do stuff };
```

I'd recommend making it a function which could return true/false :)

Comment: jquery's text() function always returns a string